# Adding a self-made app to a resume?

Tags: iphone, resume, computer-vision

Looking for opinion,

I made an iPhone app on my spare time and am proud of my achievement in self learning.  I want companies to know that I'm self driven and completed my own project.  I was wondering where would be the best area to place a self-made mobile app on a resume?  Create a separate project section?

I'm not sure it would be past work because I didn't really employ myself or anything, but I just want to mention somewhere on my resume that is noticeable enough to get companies interested.

Thanks!

Comment: A more proper place to ask that would probably one of Stack Overflow's sister sites, [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com). Do check it out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about career advice.

Comment: @Renan, I see!  I didn't know about the sister site The Workplace.  Is there a way for me to get it moved over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question may not be well-received as @Renan pointed out in the comment, but... Absolutely put it on there! Make a "recreational highlights" section or something like that to show off your spare-time projects.  I think that is a huge differentiator for a resume.  Check out [my resume](http://goo.gl/hjDKP) for an example.

Comment: I see, thanks for the example!  I was wondering, is it because you are a senior developer that you removed college organizations and awards?

I am an undergraduate, I probably should have specified that, so my resume is currently my education, work experiences (3), skills, organizations, and awards.  Do you recommend removing one of those sections to make space?  Trying to keep it one page :p

Comment: Work experience and organizations should be one single thing, no? Also, absolutely include apps you've made on your own if you think they're useful, that shows you have the spirit of a developer, and also some level of proactivity.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Awards are good, but work experience and building stuff on the side is more appealing.  Always put your best stuff first, drop the least important stuff to make room for more important stuff.  I have a couple of [blog posts on this topic](http://proseand.co.nz/tag/resume/).  You're welcome to steal all of my ideas. :)